# Multisite installation not in root - how to make live?

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I have a multisite installation running in a sub-directory on the server - purely for the reason that it has become my MO to develop a new site for a client in a "WordPress" directory while their old site is live, and then when it is ready, I change the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files and voila, the site is live.

For the first time I have a multisite (sub-directory not sub-domain) in its own folder (not in the root) and now the process is different to what I was used to.

I have googled extensively and found info on the modifications to the `.htaccess` file - but I get *"Error establishing a database connection"* error when trying to access the root on my browser. `Root.com/wordpress/` still works perfectly.

I've amended the `.htacccess` file with this code - as per WordPress.org:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And I've added the name of the subdirectory into the `index.php` file as per making a single site live - but now the establishing connection with the database error.

Could you please help with the next step - I sense I am close!

Answer (score 1):

That's an error with your database credentials, as stored in wp-config.php . Check/fix those credentials to let WP access the database.  (As the googles would tell you if you searched on the error message....)

Comment: Thank you Rick - I am not au fait with with working with WP's guts and i was too scared to change the wp-config.php file without knowing exactly what i was doing. The Googles did not give me the answer but your answer gave me the courage to make a change and it did the trick - answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After i was assured that the problem was indeed in the wp-config.php file and nowhere else, all i had to was change, under the /* Multisite */ section:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'root.com');
```

to

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'root.com/wordpress');
```

et voila!